# "Request timed out." error when setting debug="false"

Tags: asp.net

I have a page that takes a few minutes to run.  When I set `debug="false"` in the `<compilation />` tag in web.config, I get a "Request timed out." error (and internal try/catch blocks in my code get a "Thread was being aborted." error.

What is the fix to allow long pages to run in production mode?  Does debug mode have an infinite timeout?

Comment: Are you sure you need a page that takes a few minutes to run? Cant you move that functionality to a console application that you schedule?

Comment: Ehh... it's only accessed via a web form for ease of use.  It's a protected page and a scheduled task hits it nightly.  The "right" thing to do is probably kicking these tasks off via a Windows service or something, but if it ain't broke, work on something that could actually help generate revenue :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just need to increase the script timeout for page executions. It defaults to 90 seconds, so if you need more time, change it in the following system.web element (executionTimeout attribute):

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="seconds"
             maxRequestLength="kbytes"
             minFreeThreads="numberOfThreads"
             minLocalRequestFreeThreads="numberOfThreads"
             appRequestQueueLimit="numberOfRequests" 
             useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true|false"  />
```

Comment: In addition to increasing the timeout, you might also want to look into making the page asynchronous. A long running page in synchronous mode will consume a thread for the duration. By making it async, you free that ASP.NET thread so it can process other requests, while an additional thread is spawned in the background to handle your long-running request. These days, async ASP.NET pages are pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the max. duration for requests in web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" />
```

Where executionTimeout specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET. Details can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx).